# Interpreting events during prayer as signs

Tags: tefilla, segulah, hashgacha-pratit

Suppose a person is praying for parnasah as they drop a coin into a tzedakah box. At that very moment, there is a loud rumble of thunder, even though the weather conditions wouldn't seem to warrant it, and no further thunder is heard.

If someone is praying and something unusual like this happens at a significant moment in their prayers, is it appropriate to interpret the event as a sign from Heaven that the prayer has been heard (or something else)? I am referring to a case where someone has not asked for such a sign, nor were they expecting one, but the circumstances just seem too remarkable to be coincidence.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10273/5

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch 103:3 writes if one releases air from the bottom during prayer it is a bad omen if it is from the top(sneeze,burp) it is a good omen.

Comment: So can we say if a burp is a good omen, ad kama v'kama for thunder, etc?

Comment: Shulchan Aruch does not say that only this one example.

Comment: Perhaps it depends what the thunder sounds like :)